# Persisted queries in SPQR GraphQL

Tags: java, graphql-spqr

Does GraphQL-SPQR has support for PersistedQueries or not, if not
what's the suggested way of handling persisted queries in SPQR.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're referring to SPQR Spring Starter here. It currently does not have this feature built-in. I believe only Apollo Engine (Link?) does. But you should be able to use it with any GraphQL server.

A [post](https://blog.apollographql.com/persisted-graphql-queries-with-apollo-client-119fd7e6bba5) from Apollo blog says:

> Automatic persisted queries — a built-in feature when using Apollo
>   Link and Engine, works with any client or server

So you could have your SPQR-based server behind Apollo Engine, and get this and other features it offers.

I *think* you could also implement this specific feature yourself, relatively easily.
As of v0.0.4 of SPQR Spring Starter you can replace the `GraphQLServletExecutor` (or `GraphQLReactiveExecutor` if you're using WebFlux, or `GraphQLWebSocketExecutor` if you're using subscriptions):

```
@Bean
public GraphQLServletExecutor graphQLExecutor(ServletContextFactory contextFactory) {
    return new CustomExecutorThatPersistsQueries();
}
```

Comment: Hi @kaqqao, thank your for you reply. Yes I was referring to the SPQR spring boot starter project. I was looking for a endpoint that can intercept the persisted query request and get the query for given persisted query id and make the `GraphQLRequest` along with the variables and execute the request using `GraphQL` and return the result. Let me know if it make sense to share a code snippet to explains what I am talking abont.

Comment: @user2224632 Oh, I understand now. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @kaqqao Now its 2020, Thought i'd check again, Is this feature available in the recent SPQR lib now or above holds still valid ? Sorry i couldn't find much about spqr documentation.